# message is not defined, i dont get behind it

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js, message

So i cant get behind it how i can define message, i already searched a lot and tried some things but it wont work. I am a beginner so i probably just forgot where or how I have to do it.

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
        try {
        await member.send(`Hello ${member}, welcome to the PotatoHost Server! 
I want to help you and so my question is: Do you want to buy a server or do you need more informations first? \n
A: I want to buy a server
B: I need more informations first \n
Please react to this message with A or B.`)
            .then(function (message) {
                message.react("")
                message.react("")
            });

            message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '' || reaction.emoji.name == ''),
                { max: 1}).then(collected => {
                    if (collected.first().emoji.name == '') {
                        message.reply('Ok, so you want to buy a server. Let me recommend you to visit <#699374469977735208>.');
                        client.destroy();

                    }
                    else
                    message.reply('Ok, so you need more informations first. Let me recommend you to visit <#699374469977735208>.');
                })

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })

 client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about it but why you are not moving message inside the message scope?

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
        try {
        await member.send(`Hello ${member}, welcome to the PotatoHost Server! 
I want to help you and so my question is: Do you want to buy a server or do you need more informations first? \n
A: I want to buy a server
B: I need more informations first \n
Please react to this message with A or B.`)
            .then(function (message) {
                message.react("")
                message.react("")
            message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '' || reaction.emoji.name == ''),
                { max: 1}).then(collected => {
                    if (collected.first().emoji.name == '') {
                        message.reply('Ok, so you want to buy a server. Let me recommend you to visit <#699374469977735208>.');
                        client.destroy();

                    }
                    else
                    message.reply('Ok, so you need more informations first. Let me recommend you to visit <#699374469977735208>.');
                })

            });


        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })

 client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

`message` is only defined within the callback in your first `.then` function. You called `message` again after that where it is no longer defined. Shift all calls to message inside `.then` to fix this.

```
.then(function (message) {
    message.react("")
    message.react("")
    message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id && 
        (reaction.emoji.name == '' || reaction.emoji.name == ''),
        { max: 1}).then(collected => {
        if (collected.first().emoji.name == '') {
            message.reply('Ok, so you want to buy a server. Let me recommend you to visit <#699374469977735208>.');
             client.destroy();
        } else
            message.reply('Ok, so you need more informations first. Let me recommend you to visit <#699374469977735208>.');
    })
});
```

You might want to read up on scopes: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp